# Comparing list elements of two lists (with a twist)

Tags: python, list, iteration

I have two lists of integers (only positive ones): a and b. Now, I want to compare a[0] with b[0], a[1] with b[1], a[2] with b[2] and so on, but I don't know how to.

More specifically, I want to know the distance between a[0] and b[0] and so on, and save the results in a list (or, which would be even better, I want a list of percentages of, if the bigger integer would be 100%, how much percent the smaller one would be of the bigger one (f.e. 2 is 50% of 4)).

I have Python 3.7.3.

Comment: take a look at zip.

Comment: are two list of same size?

Comment: they are the same size

Answer (score 6):

You can use a list comprehension with [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip), and take the `abs` of the difference between the elements in each `tuple`:

```
[abs(i-j) for i,j in zip(l1,l2)]
```

---

And if you want the percentual difference, as you mention, you can use string formatting:

```
['{0:.2f}%'.format((min(i,j)/max(i,j))*100) for i,j in zip(l1,l2)]
```

---

Where in both cases, by zipping both lists you are creating a list of tuples, where the i-th tuple contains the i-th element from each of the argument sequences or iterables:

```
list(zip(l1,l2))
# [(8, 3), (5, 6), (2, 4), (1, 3)]
```

---

For instance:

```
l1 = [8,5,2,1]
l2 = [3,6,4,3]

['{0:.2f}%'.format((min(i,j)/max(i,j))*100) for i,j in zip(l1,l2)]
# ['37.50%', '83.33%', '50.00%', '33.33%']
```